# How to set additional query to recursive relation in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to make the orderBy parameter dynamic (not "name" as it is now)

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class,'parent_id','id')
        ->orderBy('name')
        ->with(['children' => fn($q) => $q->orderBy('name')]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me is when you call the relationship on the method `with()` and add the function as you did on the model, then you be able to pass the parameter on the fly instead since you defined the relationship.

e.g.

Relationship on model

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class,'parent_id','id');
}
```

Call the relationship

```
$data = Model::with('children' => function($query) use($parameter) {
    $query->orderBy($parameter);
});
```

Try with this solution, I'm not sure if that works, but I did something similar to apply a where conditional on the relationship

Comment: This will only work for one "layer" of this Recursive relationship. Notice how `public function children()` calls `->with('children')`? You'd need to do `::with(->with(...)->orderBy(...))->with(...)->orderBy(...)))->orderBy(...)` (which obviously won't work, since Recursive relationships can have 0-∞ layers (or until time/memory limit is exhausted)

Comment: Yes totally agree with you, but on that case He should change the logic, you can pass an array as a parameter and make a foreach() to add each orderBy 

$data = Model::with('children' => function($query) use($parameters) {
    foreach($parameters as $parameter){
        $query->orderBy($parameter);
    }
});

Comment: @TimLewis you can sort by inner relationships if connected properly with **$model->orderBy(['startDate' => 'asc', 'relationshipTableName.age' => 'desc']);** etc etc, so for Ricardo solution it works if he passes an array with the criteria (assuming he loads the relationships properly)

Comment: you can also do like **$model->orderBy('startDate', 'asc')->orderBy('relationshipTableName.age', 'desc');** Ricardo can adjust his code just slightly to accept these calls on the main parent model

Comment: @KGG Thanks for the advice, I didn't know that we can sort on that way with the relationship.field or with an array, it will look better than the foreach